# "Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added" error in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

"Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added" error in react-native

I am using 0.67 upgraded from 0.60, sunddely this error appear
I dont use any amplify library and no such thing removeListener.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing this issue after upgrading from RN v0.64 - v0.66.

I am also not using amplify, I am not sure where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was using and old version of react-navigation (2.x), I fixed the issue by just commenting and using patch-package :

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
```

in node_modules/react-navigation/src/createNavigationContainer.js

I thinks it's for deeplinking but I'm handling it myself anyway.

It's a crappy solution and I will update react-navigation very soon.

So may be it's react-navigation may be not, but one of your node module probably is trying to remove a listener that doesn't exist anymore, you should look for removeEventListener and/or removeListener

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, new version under `unstable` tag on npm,

```
"aws-amplify": "4.3.3-unstable.4"
```

checkout this github issue : [Open Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8902#issuecomment-944785716)

Comment: im not using any amplify